# Jquery .autocomplete not working after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery

Hi guys i am trying to write a title matcher, i got it working but when an ajax call is made it no longer works below is my code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

   $(document).ready(function() 
            {
                $(".course").autocomplete("look_me_up.php", 
                    {
                        width: 260,
                        matchContains: true,
                        mustMatch: true,
                        selectFirst: false
                    });

                $(".course").result(function(event, data, formatted)
                    {
                          $(this).next(".course_val").val(data[1]);
                    });
            });
```

The text box i want to update is called from a ajax request which is made first :

```
<input type="text" name="course" id="text1" value="Find Title In DB" class="course">
<input type="hidden" id="val1" class="course_val">
```

And the ajax request is :

```
function checks()
            {

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "get_data.php",
                data : "function="+"get_text",
                success : function(msg) 
                    {
                       $(update_me).html(msg);
                    }
                });
            }
```

I assume the jquery is acting up because the its trying to update a value pulled from the ajax request? I am struggling to get it to work so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $(document).ready(function()  

try to use this

Comment: what is the value of `update_me`? is that a container element which contains the `course` element

Comment: yeah it was meant to be $(document).ready(function() but id changed it and forgot to change it back the update me updates a table and populates it with the text boxes specified

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` should be before other script

Comment: Ive done that and still no luck :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be a problem with the dynamic element creation.

You have loaded some `course` elements and autocomplete was initialized on them, later you seems to be replacing those elements with new elements. Here you are not initializing autocomplete for the new elements.

The solution is to initialize the autocomplete for the dynamically added elements

```
function createCourse(els){
    els.autocomplete("look_me_up.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        mustMatch: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });

    els.result(function(event, data, formatted){
        $(this).next(".course_val").val(data[1]);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    createCourse($(".course"))
});

function checks() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "get_data.php",
        data : "function="+"get_text",
        success : function(msg)  {
            $(update_me).html(msg);
            createCourse($(".course", update_me))
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed sorry for the late reply, also thank you for the description now that i understand the problem hopefully I wont need to ask as many silly questions

Answer (score 0):

> Change

`$(document).ready(function()`

> to

`$(document).ajaxComplete(function()`

> and bingo :)